# Sharing type definitions between different OCaml files

Tags: ocaml

Say A.ml B.ml C.ml D.ml all need to define some same types

```
type a = ... 
type b = ...
```

Since I don't want duplicate codes, I put these type definitions in a single file `Shared_type.ml` and I will do `Open Shared_type` in A.ml, B.ml ...

Is there a better and elegant way to handle this problem? Also, I feel like there might be something wrong with my underlying design. What are the possible improvements?

Comment: If you truly have common code that you want to open in every module (I don't believe what you intend is a case though), in 4.02.0 you can use the `-open <module>` command during compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should put these declarations in a `Shared.mli` file containing only declarations, not definitions (you'll give definitions in `Shared.ml`). This is explained in [§2.5 modules & seperate compilation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/moduleexamples.html#sec22)

PS I strongly advise you to read *entirely* the [ocaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/) before coding any serious thing in OCaml.

Comment: I don't know if reading the entire manual is necessary; that's a bit extreme. But at least Part I and relevant sections of Part III and the std and core library in Part IV.

Comment: I believe that at least having read quickly the manual is helpful. E.g. to remember that some function already exists!